# Disable checking nonexistent partition

Tags: boot, 18.04, services, fsck

I use Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS and recently I replace my hard disk with another and change `/etc/fstab` file:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=287d1a83-ed10-4dff-8b3a-acca224d8cb0 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=36EF-F7C0  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /home was on /dev/sdb3 during installation
UUID=4229bf67-6e83-4c25-bd03-8583f3a75c5a /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=48d1eac5-afac-4deb-88ab-0b9528dc7467 none            swap    sw              0       0
# swap was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=a8c63b5b-9d21-4a72-b059-3348e4a4333b none            swap    sw              0       0
```

So, now my system boots in the right way, but **my booting time greatly increased** and in  `/var/log/boot.log`  file I found such line

```
 #/var/log/boot.log
[^[[0;1;31mFAILED^[[0m] Failed to start File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/426d7a71-bdfe-4b58-851d-9b023b968211.
See 'systemctl status "systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\\x2duuid-426d7a71\\x2dbdfe\\x2d4b58\\x2d851d\\x2d9b023b968211.service"' for details.
```

Where `426d7a71-bdfe-4b58-851d-9b023b968211` is my old partition UUID.

Here is `systemctl status "systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\\x2duuid-426d7a71\\x2dbdfe\\x2d4b58\\x2d851d\\x2d9b023b968211.service"` output:

```
● systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-426d7a71\x2dbdfe\x2d4b58\x2d851d\x2d9b023b968211.service - File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/426d7a71-bdfe-4b58-851d-9b023b968211
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-fsck@.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:systemd-fsck@.service(8)
```

It's seems like systemd-fsck ignore `/etc/fstab` file and trying to check nonexistent partition.

**How to prevent this?**